# Text effect that slide up in a overflow hidden area

Tags: jquery, css

I am searching for how to make the effect like in this one,

https://goodkidsagency.com

Where the text is "CREATIVE AGENCY FOR DARING BRANDS"

It look super simple, but I can't figure out how to do that. I use HTML, CSS and jQuery. So I don't know if there is a plugin or something. Maybe I am searching with some wrong keywords, don't know.

Comment: Corrected some English language as it was not proper.

Comment: English language corrections.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [gsap](https://greensock.com/) or [kute.js](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/) scripts , its good to deal with animations on text or everything .

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo using some CSS and js. Try it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
     jQuery('.header__title').addClass('show');
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.animated-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header__title {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
    max-width: 32rem;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    max-width: 60rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(8rem);
    transition: transform 1s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header__title.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
h1 em {
  position: relative;
}
.header__title em:before {
    background-color: rgba(249,214,61,.8);
    bottom: .05rem;
    content: "";
    height: 1.2rem;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform-origin: left;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .9s cubic-bezier(.515,.005,.185,1) 1s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: -webkit-transform .9s cubic-bezier(.515,.005,.185,1) 1s;
    transition: transform .9s cubic-bezier(.515,.005,.185,1) 1s;
    transition: transform .9s cubic-bezier(.515,.005,.185,1) 1s,-webkit-transform .9s cubic-bezier(.515,.005,.185,1) 1s;
}
.header__title.show em:before {
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="animated-text">
  <h1 class="header__title">
      Creative agency<br>for <em><i>daring brands</i></em>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Joykal, thanks for the demo. In your demo, all the text show up in the same time. Where the case from https://goodkidsagency.com tage one line at the time.

And that's the part I can't figurate out.